# In-App Purchase Sandbox Testing Failed : Purchase of this item is not currently available

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, testing, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

[image]I have implemented in-App purchases in my existing App,

In-App Purchase Product Status: **Ready To Submit**

All banking and tax-related information is set in App Store Connect.
it is around 2 days,

I am getting the ***Error Alerts*** after clicking Purchase Button of In-App purchase PopUp :

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

We have the same issue. In the early same question here, the dude proposes to change the base price currency for in-app. I've tried to change it to UK, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured it out:

[image]

Your "Base country or Region" currency needs to match your company's.
In my case, when I changed it to SEK, it started working.

Hope it helps!

Comment: This solution doesn't work in my case. US company + USD still doesn't work.